# getting problem in transposing an 2D array

Tags: java, arrays, compiler-errors, transpose

i have written a code to transpose an aray it works when i took small arrays dimensions like 3*3 but when i took array size 4*5 it gives me array out of bound error.i am a beginner.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
public class Transpose {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("enter rows and cols: ");
        int r = sc.nextInt();
        int c = sc.nextInt();
        long a[][] = new long [r][c];
        long transpose[][] = new long [r][c];

        System.out.print("enter"+" " +r*c+" "+"elements");
        for(int i =0; i < a.length; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < a[i].length; j++){
                a[i][j] = sc.nextInt();
            }
        }

        for(int i =0; i < a.length; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < a[i].length; j++){
                System.out.print(" "+a[i][j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < a.length ; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < a[i].length; j++){
                long temp = a[i][j];
                transpose[i][j] = a[j][i];
                a[i][j] = temp;
            }
        }

        System.out.println();
        for(int i =0; i < transpose.length; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < transpose[i].length; j++){
                System.out.print(" "+transpose[i][j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `long transpose[][] = new long [r][c];` -> `long transpose[][] = new long [c][r];`

Comment: `transpose[i][j] = a[j][i];` -> `transpose[j][i] = a[i][j];`

Comment: There's no need for the `temp` variable.

Comment: thx bruh you solved my problrm !!